# Formato de DateTime C#

Tags: c#, bootstrap, datetime, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Estoy realizando un proyecto en ASP.NET Core MVC (NET 5.0).
En una de las vistas de mi controlador implementé un selector de dates Desde-Hasta por medio del package bootstrap-datepicker de la siguiente manera dentro de un BeginForm:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Desde - Hasta</strong>
    <div class="input-group input-daterange form-group">
        <input id="Desde" type="text" name="Desde" class="form-control" placeholder="Desde" value="@ViewBag.Desde" required />
        <div class="input-group-addon">A</div>
        <input id="Hasta" type="text" name="Hasta" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasta" value="@ViewBag.Hasta" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

Le agrego la configuración de bootstrap-datepicker:

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOnFocus: true,
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'es'
});
```

Hago la llamada en el backend de la siguiente manera:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(DateTime? desde, DateTime? hasta)
{
}
```

El dato en la vista se visualiza de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir correcto, ya que me formateó a lo seteado: dd/mm/yyyy

pero al dar el submit en el backend me llega de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, me invirtió los valores de la vista, en el dd me seteo un **06** y en el mm un **01**, es como si en el momento de dar el submit el formato del datepicker haya sido mm/dd/yyyy.

Desde ya, gracias.
Un saludo, estoy atento a cualquier replica.

Comment: Si necesitas guardarlo de esa forma, transforma la cadena para que puedas obtener el resultado deseado por ejemplo   -    desde.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")